# How can i handle axios error in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga

Is there a way to capture the error response from axios in a try/catch redux-saga?

I have the following axios logging function:

```
export const login = (username, password) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
  
    const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
    
    return axios
        .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts-api/login', body, config)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => error.response.data)
};
```

which returns

```
{user: {…}, token: "b5d36ec9086f7f2403a02c2e8d70695e85a48cad2d81e39c9b31fddaa759a79e"}
```

when the password and username is correct or

```
{non_field_errors: ["Incorrect Credentials"]}
```

when  password or username is not correct.

The login function is called in the following redux-saga generator:

```
export function* signIn({ payload: { username, password } }) {
    try {
        const response = yield login(username, password)
        let { user, token } = yield response
        yield console.log(user)
        yield console.log(token)
    } catch(e) {
        yield console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to capture the error response from axios ( in this case {non_field_errors: ["Incorrect Credentials"]} )in redux-saga catch?

Now with incorect user credential user and token are set to undefined and function is not moving on to redux-saga catch.

Comment: The promise you return from the login function will never reject (i.e. cause error) because all errors will be caught by the catch in this promise chain.

Comment: remove the `.catch(error => error.response.data)`

Comment: btw, all the 'yield's after `yield login` are useless

Comment: without .catch(error=>error.response.data) i get


```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

and I lose access to {non_field_errors: ["Incorrect Credentials"]}

Comment: sure, it will be in `e.response.data`